# Using Duckdb Node.js binding

Tags: javascript, node.js, duckdb

I am stuck for several days with [duckDB nodeJS binding](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/nodejs/overview) from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/duckdb). I am simply trying a database creation with:

```
import * as duckdb from 'duckdb'
   
const db = new duckdb.Database(':memory:');
```

but this triggers the following error:

```
const db = new duckdb.Database(':memory:');
           ^

TypeError: duckdb.Database is not a constructor
    at file:///home/juju/workspace/gridtiler/npm/bin/gridtiler.js:64:12
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:192:25)
    at async DefaultModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:40:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:66:12)

Node.js v20.4.0
```

while `Database` class is loaded. The execution does not recognize it as a class, apparently.

Is there something I missed?

A `console.log(duckdb)` returns:

```
[Module: null prototype] {
  default: {
    Database: [Function: Database],
    Connection: [Function: Connection],
    Statement: [Function: Statement],
    QueryResult: [Function: QueryResult],
    ERROR: -1,
    OPEN_READONLY: 1,
    OPEN_READWRITE: 0,
    OPEN_CREATE: 0,
    OPEN_FULLMUTEX: 0,
    OPEN_SHAREDCACHE: 0,
    OPEN_PRIVATECACHE: 0
  }
}
```

which shows that `Database` class should be available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... Just replacing `import * as duckdb from 'duckdb'` with `import duckdb from 'duckdb'` solved the issue.

Otherwise, `duckdb.default.Database` should be used instead of `duckdb.Database`.